# Files disappeared in folders in windows 7

Tags: windows-7

All my files in a folder (and its subfolders) disappeared. However, properties showed that the files are still there.  And when I did a search, it also showed the files still being there. What can I do?

Comment: This sounds like filesystem corruption caused by the indexies for the files in the MFT being deleted.  File recovery might help in a case like this.

Comment: I have seen malware do something like this before, but it changed most of the files to shortcuts.  You may try using the attrib command in a command screen. Type attrib -r -h -s /s d/ c:\folder_name

Answer (score 1):

please verify that they are not hidden by right clicking and making sure **Hidden** option is unselected. Then, you could run `chkdsk /f` command as administrator. If that does not retrieve your files, you can try running `chkdsk /r` command.